# How do I get the name (string) of a compiled function?

Tags: elisp

I have this advice in place that executes the called function over the whole buffer if a region is not selected. But I would also like to print a message that tells the user that the function they just called acted on the whole buffer.

```el
(defun modi/whole-buffer-if-not-region (orig-fn &rest args)
  (save-excursion
    (if (region-active-p) ; do the default thing if a region is selected
        (apply orig-fn args)
      (let (fn-name) ; indent the whole buffer otherwise
        (apply orig-fn (list (point-min) (point-max)))
        (setq fn-name (cl-case (type-of orig-fn)
                        ('subr              (subr-name orig-fn))
                        ;; ('compiled-function (symbol-name orig-fn)) ; doesn't work
                        (t     orig-fn)))
        (message "Executed %s on the whole buffer" fn-name)))))

(advice-add #'indent-region :around #'modi/whole-buffer-if-not-region)
(advice-add #'eval-region   :around #'modi/whole-buffer-if-not-region)
```

Using the above code,

- If I do `M-x eval-region` without selecting a region, I see the message `Executed eval-region on the whole buffer`.
- I would like to get a similar message when I do `M-x indent-region` without selecting a region. `symbol-name` does not work here as I learned that the `indent-region` function is of the type `'compiled-function`

With the above code I get the below when I do `M-x indent-region` without region selection:

```
Executed #[770 \211\203A \303!\262\212b\210\304 \262b\210n\204 \305y\210`W\2038 `\306\307w\210`|\210l\2042 \310\311"\210\305y\210\202 \307\211\223\210)\202\324 \203u \212b\210\304 \262b\210\312!`W\203p \313!\204j n\203g l\204j c\210\305y\210\202S \210)\202\324    \203\201    "\210\202\324 \212\314!\262b\210\315 ?\205\225 \316\317`#`W\203\305 n\203\243 l\204\246 \320 \210\305y\210\211\203\225 \211`\211\247\203\273 \211@Y\203\300 \321"\210\266\202\225 \211\203\315 \322!\210\307\211\223\266)\323\211\207 [fill-prefix indent-region-function deactivate-mark prefix-numeric-value point-marker 1    nil indent-to 0 regexp-quote looking-at copy-marker minibufferp make-progress-reporter Indenting region... indent-according-to-mode progress-reporter-do-update progress-reporter-done t] 9 2037903 r
P] on the whole buffer
```

**How do I extract the `compiled-function` name (`indent-region` in this case)?**

### Solution

Thanks to **@abo-abo**'s solution below, I got this working as I wanted using the below:

```el
(defmacro modi/add-whole-buffer-if-not-region-advice (symbol)
  "Advice SYMBOL function (that originally acts on a region) to act on the
whole buffer if a region is not selected."
  `(advice-add ,symbol :around (lambda (orig-fn &rest args)
                                 (save-excursion
                                   ;; Execute the original SYMBOL function if
                                   ;; it is called indirectly. Example: we do
                                   ;; not want to trigger this advice if
                                   ;; `eval-region' is called via `eval-defun'.
                                   (if (or (not (eq ,symbol this-command))
                                           (use-region-p))
                                       (apply orig-fn args)
                                     (apply orig-fn (list (point-min) (point-max)))
                                     (message "Executed %s on the whole buffer"
                                              (propertize
                                               (symbol-name ,symbol)
                                               'face
                                               'font-lock-function-name-face)))))))

(modi/add-whole-buffer-if-not-region-advice #'indent-region)
(modi/add-whole-buffer-if-not-region-advice #'eval-region)
```

Comment: Function object isn't something that has a name... it can be pointed to by many symbols, so your question can't have a good answer. However, since you are adding these advices, you could maintain a list of functions you advised and look for the name in that list.

Comment: @wvxvw Ah, I wished it were possible to get the name of the symbol used to trigger that sub/compiled-function/..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the name from `orig-fn`, since it's just a byte-compiled lambda, and you can't get a name of lambda.

You can use something (simpler) instead:

```cl
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
(defun modi-add-region-advice (symbol)
  (advice-add
   symbol
   :around (lambda (orig-fn &rest args)
             (save-excursion
               (if (region-active-p)
                   (apply orig-fn args)
                 (message "Executed %s on the whole buffer" symbol))))))
(modi-add-region-advice 'indent-region)
```

Comment: The `symbol` is not passed onto the `lambda`; I am getting `Symbol's value as variable is void: symbol`. Hmm.. I thought that simply adding `symbol` to the list of `lambda` args would work.. but it doesn't. It now prints `Executed nil on the whole buffer`.

Comment: I finally got it working by making that `defun` a `defmacro` and evaluating the value of `symbol` in the macro using `,symbol`. Thanks! I don't think it's possible to use `defun` here.. is it?

Comment: Note the comment that sets `lexical-binding`. It's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when this became possible but there is now an built in emacs function to get the name of a compiled function called `subr-name`

This can be used for conditionals as OP was looking for. For instance I am using it in the following function:

```emacs-lisp
(defun json-pretty-print-dwim+ (orig-fun &rest args)
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (save-excursion
      (condition-case nil
          (apply orig-fun args)
        (error
         (if (string-suffix-p "buffer" (subr-name orig-fun))
             (json-pretty-print-buffer+)
           (json-pretty-print-next+)))))
    (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
    (read-only-mode 1)))

(advice-add 'json-pretty-print :around #'json-pretty-print-dwim+)

(advice-add 'json-pretty-print-buffer :around #'json-pretty-print-dwim+)
```

Comment: I think that's largely a side-effect of native-compilation turning lisp functions into effective `subr`s, so YMMV (bearing in mind that even with native compilation enabled, if *recompilation* is needed then Emacs will run the non-native lisp code in the interim, until the new native code is ready to load).

Answer (score 0):

Small comment : IMO, the body of the question (in particular the part entitled "Solution") is not really related to the title of the question. I suggested an edit of the title, but it was rejected. I think abo-abo's answer is the best to solve the problem described in the body, so now what follows is a solution to the problem stated in the title.

---

As others have said, the problem has no general solution : a function could very well have no name at all. So let us assume that it does have a name, i.e. there is a symbol (interned in `obarray`) which holds that function in its function cell.

The way to find out the name of a function is to loop through obarray and check every symbol for one that matches. This is pretty simple to write with mapatoms, and left as an exercise to the reader.

But there is one added difficulty : advices. If you advised indent-region, the function slot of that symbol no longer is the original indent-region. So the above method will not do what you want, and you have to dissect the function cell to check if it was advised, and what was the original function.

Now that the job description is done, to the code !

```
(defun yf/find-function-in-symbols (function &optional advicep)
  "Find FUNCTION in obarray and return a corresponding symbol, or nil.
When ADVICEP is non-nil, also return symbol if it is an advised
version of FUNCTION."
  (catch 'found
    (mapatoms (lambda (sym)
        (when (fboundp sym)
          (let ((symfun (symbol-function sym)))
            (when (or (eq symfun function)
                  (and advicep
                   (eq (advice--cd*r symfun)
                       function)))
              (throw 'found sym))))))
    nil))

(defun modi/whole-buffer-if-not-region (orig-fn &rest args)
  (save-excursion
    (if (region-active-p)
        (progn
          ;; do the default thing if a region is selected
          (message "Executed %s as usual" (yf/find-function-in-symbols orig-fn t))
          (apply orig-fn args))
      ;; indent the whole buffer otherwise
      (apply orig-fn (list (point-min) (point-max)))
      (message "Executed %s on the whole buffer" (yf/find-function-in-symbols orig-fn t)))))

(advice-add #'indent-region :around #'modi/whole-buffer-if-not-region)
(advice-add #'eval-region   :around #'modi/whole-buffer-if-not-region)
```

---

Last comment : when `yf/find-function-in-symbols` is not given its optional ADVICEP argument, it gives an answer to the easier problem where no advising is involved.